# rxjs: map with index

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to know the index of the current object when map is used. For example:

```
x = [3,2,6]
from(x).pipe(
 map(index, val => (val, index))
).subscribe((val, index) => console.log(val, index))
```

Expected output

```
3, 0
2, 1
6, 2
```

Basically, I want to know the index of the element in the array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

it is very close to what you've tried

```
from(x).pipe(
 map((val, index) => [val, index]) // here we transform event to array (call it tuple if you like)
).subscribe(([val, index]) => console.log(val, index)) // here in params we destructure tuple to values again
```

Comment: Is this index, is the index of the array? Since observables are asynchonous, if the output values are for example  2, 3 ,6 then what will be the index for those values? Is it still going to be (2, 0), (3,1), (6,2) or (2, 1), (3,0), (6,2)

Comment: `map` operator just counts index with the events, the item which comes nth will be passed with (n-1) index